# How can I bind compile using comint to a key combination

Tags: emacs

I currently bind compile to C-x c. I know I can run compile in comint mode by using C-u C-x c but I'd prefer to just bind it to C-x c directly. I can't fathom how to do this without copying the whole of the compile function from compile.el, tweaking it and binding that. Is there a better way?

Edit: To clarify my sloppy language, I don't wish to bind C-x c whilst in comint mode. I wish to cause C-x c to run 'compile using comint mode. I currently have C-x bound to 'compile. I can do what I want by typing C-u C-x c but I'd prefer to just be able to type C-x c to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* this works...

```
(defun c-w-c ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'compile t (vector 21 (this-command-keys-vector))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x c") 'c-w-c)
```

the '21' prepended into the vector is the ctrl-u prefix key, and it seems to fool the compile function into thinking it was called with C-u C-x c.

**Edit:**

It didn't work, but this does:

```
(defun c-w-c ()
  (interactive)
  (setq current-prefix-arg '(4))
  (call-interactively 'compile))
```

Comment: That works perfectly and is exactly the type of thing I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this :

```
(global-set-key [(C-f5)] 'compile)
(global-set-key [(f5)] 'recompile)
```

It binds `compile` to <kbd>C-f5</kbd> and each time you want to recompile with the same command as you've given in `compile`, just type <kbd>f5</kbd>. It works whatever the major mode you're currently in.

For your case, do like this :

```
(global-set-key [?\C-x ?c] 'compile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for this?

```
(define-key comint-mode-map (kbd "C-x c") 'compile)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

```
(define-key comint-mode-map (kbd "C-x c")
  (lambda (command)
    (interactive
     (list
      (let ((command (eval compile-command)))
        (if (or compilation-read-command current-prefix-arg)
            (compilation-read-command command)
          command))))
    (compile command t)))
```

It's ugly because it duplicates the "interactive" spec from the `compile` command.

Comment: I'd considered this one but disregarded it because it involved cutting and pasting so much code. Thanks.